# How to run asp.net 4.0 websites on asp.net 3.5.?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net, c#-4.0

i have an application developed in 4.0 asp.net. and i want to make some changes but i am using 3.5 asp.net.

is it possible?  or i will have to download 4.0 version.

i modified the web config file according to 3.5 version........but it does not work.

Comment: It is better to upgrade to 4.0 bcoz there are so many thing except webconfig you need to change or may 3.5 not support the 4.0 featurers which is used in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't like .NET 3.5 to .NET 2.0, .NET 4 is a significant update. It's better to install .NET 4.